# How to construct one-step-method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Let $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable function. For $L>0$ the initial value problem $y'(x)=y(x)+g(y(x))$ for $x\in [0, L]$,

$y(0)=1 \\$ is given.
Construct an one-step-method for 
\begin{align}
y_0 &:=1, \\
y_{n+1} &:= exp(h_n)y_n+h_ng(y_n),& n&=0,1,...,N-1.
\end{align}

Comment: Why are you asking to construct a method that you then immediately specify? What exactly is your task? If you are to apply the method, then what is $g$ for this example?

Answer (score 0):

What is the question? You have something that looks like the exponential Euler method.

If you consider $z(x)=e^{-x}y(x)$, then 
$$
z'(x)=e^{-x}(y'(x)-y(x))=e^{-x}g(y(x))=e^{-x}g(e^xz(x))
$$
and the Euler method for $z$, translated back in terms of $y$, gives
$$
z_{n+1}=z_n+he^{-x_n}g(e^{x_n}z_n)\implies y_{n+1}=e^hy_n+he^hg(y_n)
$$
As $he^h=h+O(h^2)$, this is equivalent to the given method modulo terms of the error order of the Euler method.